# Match a filter dict to another one - Python

Tags: python, filter

I have the following configuration file, it's a .yml with the following fields.

```
filter:
    mic :
      - 'XMAD'
      - 'XSTUB'
    cfi :
      - 'CF5334'
```

My problem is the following one.

I am loading rows from a XML file, they have the following structure.

```
{'isin': 'CA86882A1093', 'cfi': 'ECNXFR', 'currency': 'EUR', 'mic': 'FRAB', 'date': '2019-02-19'}
```

With my .yml configuration filter field, I only want to accept all ones that follow my filter, in this case this is my filter.

```
{'mic': ['XMAD', 'XSTUB'], 'cfi': ['CF5334']}
```

As you can see, they can be list, in this case my filter only allows to upload those that have in mic XMAD or XSTUB and cfi only can be 'CF5334'.

My code works fine if they are only just one value, but it doesn't work if I have a list of possible values as you can see in the mic field.

Here is my code.

```
for row in xml_file:
    setf = self.filter.items()
    if setf in (row.items() & setf):
        yield security
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could invert the logic and search the values from row in filter under the same key, if present. Code could be (thanks to the Python `for ... else ...`):

```
for row in xml_file:
    for key, value in row.items():
        if key in filter and row[key] not in filter[key]:
            break
    else:
        yield row
```